# Cannot run program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I started learning C programming with `C Programming Language` by **Denis M Ritchie** I am trying to execute program from that book

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     /* count lines in input */
     main()
     {
         int c, nl;
         nl = 0;
         while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
         if (c == '\n')
         ++nl;
         printf("%d\n", nl);

         getchar();

    }
```

However all I get is blank console and when I type text and press enter,no value is displayed.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 IDE.

Comment: may I ask what is the reason for downvoting it ?

Comment: You cannot _run_ it? I cannot _compile_ it and the error messages are pretty obvious. https://ideone.com/4xYDl5

Comment: What it is supposed to do ?

Comment: @Melebius but I cant see any error messages

Comment: pressing F5 to build and run the program doesn't work?

Comment: @CyberSpock All i can see is blank console but when I type my text and hit enter I am not getting the value of `nl`

Comment: Then do CTRL-F5, after the F5 the program runs and terminates so the console window closes. With CTRL-F5 it stays open. Also the stop input use F7 after entering characters in the console.

Comment: @kyle  Or use `GetChar` as you use Visual stdio.

Comment: notice this line `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`....any pointers?

Comment: Just noticed your post was edited to remove the last call to `getchar(c);`.  Put it back, as the last line, but without the argument (as several answers have suggested):  simply put:  getchar(); as the last line and because it is a blocking function, your stdout console will stay visible until you enter a key (any key).  In this manner, your results should be visible to you.  (`printf("%d\n", nl);` should result in a write to stdout )

Comment: It might make sense you learn how to use VC's debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you posted here is for counting number of lines.

> Q. However all I get is blank console and when I type text and press
>   enter,no value is displayed

A. Yes it shows nothing because `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` waits until you enter EOF (use ctrl + z then you will get number for lines).

Comment: Ctrl-C is expected to end the program immidiately.

Answer (score 0):

```
getchar(c);
```

See declaration of `getchar`.

```
       int getchar(void)
```

It doesn't take any parameter. Didn't it gave you error.

And `main` should be `int main`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. First, main has to have a type, usually int

```
- main()
+ int main()
```

and your program should return an exit status

Secondly getchar takes no arguments, and returns the input

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm

```
- getchar(c)
+ c = getchar()
```

You can compile your program by calling

```
gcc -Wall test.c -o test
```

Where test.c is your code, and test is the binary. -Wall will show all the "warning" (errors that don't interfere with the program execution)

Comment: He’s using MSVC, not GCC.

Comment: well, then I don't know what's the equivalent command-line, I'll be glad to get my answer edited by someone who knows

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you use Windows, it's better to add:

```
system("pause");
```

Moreover to use system("pause"), only in Windows, you need to include another library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You can see your results but the problem here, is that you have an infinite loop. Yo need to check the \n, count and when you have a specific number, you leave from the loop.